# admin-on-rest: How to set the value of a TextField with an option selected in a DefaultOptionsField

Tags: admin-on-rest

I have a `SimpleForm` within an `EditView`, where the `SimpleForm` contains  a `DefaultOptionsField` and a `TextField`.

The idea is to select an option in the `DefaultOptionsField`, which then updates the value of the `TextField`.

I can make this work by updating the `TextField` on `DefaultOptionsField` `onChange` using basic JavaScript, but I would prefer a more Admin-on-Rest and React-like way to set the `TextField`'s value. Yet somehow the `EditView` layer seems to complicate things for me - I have yet to find a simple, clean and elegant way to make the `TextField` and `DefaultOptionsField` interact in that vein.

Is there maybe some basic example code of how I might structure such a solution within Admin-on-Rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case pretty much describes AOR Dependent input. Check it out here

https://github.com/marmelab/aor-dependent-input

Comment: Great. Just FYI aor-dependent-input is slowly being merged into AOR core so do check status on site and use accordingly.

Comment: Nope, `aor-permissions` has been merged into AOR core but there are no plans for `aor-dependent-input`

Comment: Aah. Sorry for that.